# Returning nested structs in solidity reverts with error

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

My class structure looks similar to this:

```
struct A { 
  uint8 foo;
  address bar;
}

struct B {
  A foo;
  int64 bar;
}


struct C {
  uint8 foo;
  ...
  B[] bar;
}
```

I have a hardhat test suite which have contract X and contract Y, contract X contains the structures above, and contract Y attempts to read struct C using X's public return function.

When i comment out C.bar, everything works fine. But when i try to return C.bar, i get the error:

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data
```

I suspect it's throwing the ABI encoder out of whack, but does anyone know if Solidity officially supports the returning of these types of structures?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are recieving this error because you need pass the key to access one of the C.bar entries.

For example, to access the first item in C.bar array, you can use:

```
C.bar[0]
```